# Equal vertical space between images and lines of text

Tags: css, baseline

I am trying to convert a design to HTML/CSS with equal amount of vertical space between the image and text, but unable to do so.  The designer created this is 20px margin between the image, title, and desc, but due to the way CSS is processed with line height, the space is not the same between all these elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/r9370Lxr/

```
 <div class="teaser-image">
     <img src="teaser1.png">
 </div>
 <div class="teaser-title">At Your Service</div>
 <div class="teaser-desc">
     blah blah blah
 </div> 


.teaser-image, .teaser-title, .teaser-desc {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 21.6px;
 }

.teaser-title {
    font-family: "myriad-pro-condensed",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}

.teaser-desc {
   font-size: 16px; 
   font-family: "myriad-pro-condensed",sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: How do you want your output to be?

Comment: I'd like there to be a 20px margin below each element and actually look that way in a browser.

Comment: There is no easy fix to this problem. Your options are to either create negative margins on each item to 'reduce' them to the proper spacing, or to have different margins depending on the element combination.

Comment: They look pretty much the same to me, but 'look' and 'are' are not necessarily the same, especially with fonts where you have all kinds of stems and loops sticking out, influencing the apparent boundaries.

Comment: Isn't there a systematic way of doing this that can take the guessing game out of the equation?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan I beg to differ. There is an easy solution.

Comment: hello, what is the size of image,  20px margin from what to what (any backgrounds in div , or borders ?) div to div or text to text to image ?

Comment: @hungerstar I'd love to see it, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Set the `line-height` of the elements that need the 20px margin to `1`. Setting to `1` means that the line height will be equal to the current font size, as in, 100% the font size. Some examples:

**`line-height: 1`**

font size = 20, line height = 20

**`line-height: 1.5`**

font size = 20, line height = 30 (20 x 1.5)

**HTML**

```html
 <div class="teaser-image">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/500x50/">
 </div>
 <div class="teaser-title">At Your Service</div>
 <div class="teaser-desc">
     blah blah blah
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.teaser-image,
.teaser-title,
.teaser-desc {
    margin: 20px 0;
    line-height: 1;
 }
.teaser-image {
    font-size: 0;
}
.teaser-title {
    font-family: "myriad-pro-condensed",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
.teaser-desc {
   font-size: 16px; 
   font-family: "myriad-pro-condensed",sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ojvpp53/

For `.teaser-image` I set the font size to zero so that the descender height is removed from around the image.

Comment: This didn't fix it.  The teaser-desc text actually needs to have line-height: 21.6px; between the lines.

Comment: Then you will have to subtract _1.6px_ from the margin for `.teaser-desc`. Not too hard to do. If you're going to increase the line height beyond the font size then you're going to have to adjust the margin accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if it is about image not standing at the edge, then, vertical-align should be the thing to reset:

```css
.teaser-image, .teaser-title, .teaser-desc {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 21.6px;    
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px;/* show me ! */
 }

.teaser-title {
    font-family: "myriad-pro-condensed",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}

.teaser-desc {
   font-size: 16px; 
   font-family: "myriad-pro-condensed",sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
}

img {vertical-align:top;}/* get close to me :) */
```

```html
 <div class="teaser-image">
     <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100&text=teaser">
 </div>
 <div class="teaser-title">At Your Service</div>
 <div class="teaser-desc">
     blah blah blah
 </div>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZGKjLW